# Kibana Post Search - Expected [START_OBJECT] but found [VALUE_STRING]

Tags: c#, kibana, rest-client, elasticsearch-dsl

Please help me with this problem.

I have a .net core client like this:

```
var client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = new Uri(Host);
        client.AddDefaultHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Resource = "_search";           
        request.AddJsonBody(queryDslKibana);
        request.Method = Method.POST;
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
```

Uri: 
   http://URL:PORT/_search

the queryDslKibana is the following:

```
{"query":{"match":{"message":".Txt"}}} 



It runs on postman gracefully but the response on .net is: 

 {
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [{
            "type": "parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Expected [START_OBJECT] but found [VALUE_STRING]",
            "line": 1,
            "col": 1
        }],
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Expected [START_OBJECT] but found [VALUE_STRING]",
        "line": 1,
        "col": 1
    },
    "status": 400
 }
```

Please help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that the variable "queryDslKibana" does not have a suitable JSON format, when using the method "**AddJsonBody**()" it is important that the object has the appropriate format.
The "**AddJsonBody**()" method serializes the object you send, so you should first try an anonymous object.

Something like that:

```
var requestObject = new {query = new {match = new {message = ".txt"}}};
```

That should result in the JSON you need:

```
{"query": {"match": {"message": ". Txt"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @michael .

The final code is:

to kibana api to the _search endpoint.

The problem was the .net RestClient because I have to send an object ( anonimous object or strong typed object) as you said so...

The answer on code is:

```
        var client = new RestClient();
        client.BaseUrl = new Uri(Host);
        client.AddDefaultHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        var request = new RestRequest();
        request.Resource = "_search";
        //{"query":{"match":{"message":"SEPP"}}}
        request.AddJsonBody(new { query = new { match = new { message = "SEPP" } } });
        request.Method = Method.POST;
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

        IRestResponse response = client.ExecutePostTaskAsync(request).Result;
```